# Export material with emission factor and color

Tags: materials, shaders, export, emission

I have a material that I want to export to a gltf scene. There is an emission map, an emission color and a emission factor (6). Currently I have the emission map connected to the principled BSDF shader and also there the color. But I can't seem to also export the factor that way. If I use an "Add Shader" with an "Emission Shader" I can specify a factor, but sadly no color. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures